# Immutable class?

Tags: java, string, immutability

How can one make a Java class immutable, what is the need of immutability and is there any advantage to using this?

Comment: There is a introduction for immutable class: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=A48AE37C845621800778D6590D53AF90?Id=29

Comment: check this `@Immutable` annotation from [jcabi-aspects](http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-aspects/annotation-immutable.html)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769607

Comment: Java SE 16 makes it amazingly easier to create an immutable class. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/65976915/10819573

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**What is an immutable object?**

An immutable object is one that will not change state after it is instantiated.

**How to make an object immutable?**

In general, an immutable object can be made by defining a class which does not have any of its members exposed, and does not have any setters.

The following class will create an immutable object:

```
class ImmutableInt {
  private final int value;

  public ImmutableInt(int i) {
    value = i;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

As can be seen in the above example, the value of the `ImmutableInt` can only be set when the object is instantiated, and by having only a getter (`getValue`) the object's state cannot be changed after instantiation.

However, there must be care taken that all objects that are referenced by the object must be immutable as well, or it could be possible to change the state of the object.

For example, allowing an reference to an array or `ArrayList` to be obtained through an getter will allow the internal state to change by changing the array or collection:

```
class NotQuiteImmutableList<T> {
  private final List<T> list;

  public NotQuiteImmutableList(List<T> list) {
    // creates a new ArrayList and keeps a reference to it.
    this.list = new ArrayList(list); 
  }

  public List<T> getList() {
    return list;
  }
}
```

The problem with the above code is, that the `ArrayList` can be obtained through `getList` and be manipulated, leading to the state of the object itself to be altered, therefore, not immutable.

```
// notQuiteImmutableList contains "a", "b", "c"
List<String> notQuiteImmutableList= new NotQuiteImmutableList(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));

// now the list contains "a", "b", "c", "d" -- this list is mutable.
notQuiteImmutableList.getList().add("d");
```

One way to get around this problem is to return a copy of an array or collection when called from a getter:

```
public List<T> getList() {
  // return a copy of the list so the internal state cannot be altered
  return new ArrayList(list);
}
```

**What is the advantage of immutability?**

The advantage of immutability comes with concurrency. It is difficult to maintain correctness in mutable objects, as multiple threads could be trying to change the state of the same object, leading to some threads seeing a different state of the same object, depending on the timing of the reads and writes to the said object.

By having an immutable object, one can ensure that all threads that are looking at the object will be seeing the same state, as the state of an immutable object will not change.

Comment: Thread safety (important for concurrency) is not the only advantage of immutability; it also means you don't have to make defensive copies of objects, and it prevents bugs because you can't by mistake modify objects that are not supposed to be modified.

Comment: Instead of returning a copy of the list, you can also `return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);` to return a read-only view on the list.

Comment: The class has to be made `final` too. Otherwise it can be extended with a setter method (or other kinds of mutating methods and mutable fields).

Comment: @AbhinavSarkar Doesn't have to be `final` if the class only has `private` fields as they cannot be accessed from subclasses.

Comment: @icza  class has to be final,because we have public getter method,we can extend the class and override the getter method and then change the field in our way..so it is not immutable anymore

Comment: @sunil How do you change a private field from a method in subclass?

Comment: Oracle documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html) says `Don't allow subclasses to override methods.`

Comment: Java SE 16 makes it amazingly easier to create an immutable class. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65976915/10819573

Answer (score 19):

In addition to the answers already given, I'd recommend reading about immutability in Effective Java, 2nd Ed., as there are some details that are easy to miss (e.g. defensive copies). Plus, Effective Java 2nd Ed. is a must-read for every Java developer.

Comment: This is the exact resource to look at. The benefits that are mentioned range right from less error prone code to thread safety.

Answer (score 7):

You make a class immutable like this:

```
public final class Immutable
{
    private final String name;

    public Immutable(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() { return this.name; } 

    // No setter;
}
```

Following are the requirements to make a Java class immutable:

- **Class** must be declared as `final` (So that child classes can’t be created)
- **Members** in the class must be declared as `final` (So that we can’t change the value of it after object creation)
- **Write Getter methods** for all the variables in it to get **Members** values
- **No Setters methods**

Immutable classes are useful because
 - They're thread-safe.
 - They also express something deep about your design: "Can't change this.", When it applies, it's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 5):

Immutability can be achieved mainly in two ways:

- using `final` instance attributes to avoid reassignment
- using a class interface that simply doesn't allow any operation that is able to modify what is inside your class (just **getters** and no **setters**

Advantages of immutability are the assumptions that you can make on these object:

- you gain the no-side effect rule (that is really popular on functional programming languages) and allows you to use objects in a concurrent environment easier, since you know that they can't be changed in a atomic or non atomic way when they are used by many threads
- implementations of languages can treat these objects in a different way, placing them in zones of memory that are used for static data, enabling faster and safer use of these objects (this is what happens inside the JVM for strings)

Comment: Immutable is not the same as equal side effect free. For example, an immutable object could produce side effects such as logging to a file. It is slightly inaccurate to say making an object immutable also makes it side effect free.

Comment: @Grundleflek, I think this may be splitting hairs.  The class isn't immutable if it modifies a log file as part of its contract and that log file is accessible to other classes. If the log file is hidden from other classes, and not part of the class's contract then the class is effectively immutable and really for all intents and purposes side-effect free.  The (unsourced) introduction on the Wikipedia side effect page reads "...an expression is said to have a side effect if, in addition to producing a value, it also modifies some state or has an observable interaction with calling functions."

Answer (score 3):

Immutable classes cannot reassign values after it is instantiated.The constructor assign values to its private variables. Until the object becomes null, values cannot be changed due to unavailability of setter methods.

to be immutable should satisfy following,

- Al the variables should be **private**.
- No **mutator** methods(setters) are provided.
- Avoid method overriding by making class final(Strong Immutability)
  or methods final(Week     immutability).
- Clone deeply if it contain non primitive or mutable classes.

---

```
/**
* Strong immutability - by making class final
*/
public final class TestImmutablity {

// make the variables private
private String Name;

//assign value when the object created
public TestImmutablity(String name) {
this.Name = name;
}

//provide getters to access values
public String getName() {

return this.Name;
}
}
```

Advanteges:
Immutable objects contains its initialized values until it dies.

[java-immutable-classes-short-note](http://javaeyerange.blogspot.com/2016/08/java-immutable-classes-short-note.html)

Answer (score 3):

**How can one make a Java class immutable?**

From JDK 14+ which has [JEP 359](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359), we can use "*`records`*". It is the simplest and hustle free way of creating Immutable class.

A record class is a shallowly **immutable**, transparent carrier for a fixed set of fields known as the record `components` that provides a `state` description for the record. Each `component` gives rise to a `final` field that holds the provided value and an `accessor` method to retrieve the value. The field name and the accessor name match the name of the component.

Let consider the example of creating an immutable rectangle

```
record Rectangle(double length, double width) {}
```

No need to declare any constructor, no need to implement equals & hashCode methods. Just any Records need a name and a state description.

```
var rectangle = new Rectangle(7.1, 8.9);
System.out.print(rectangle.length()); // prints 7.1
```

If you want to validate the value during object creation, we have to explicitly declare the constructor.

```
public Rectangle {

    if (length <= 0.0) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
  }
```

The record's body may declare static methods, static fields, static initializers, constructors, instance methods, and nested types.

**Instance Methods**

```
record Rectangle(double length, double width) {

  public double area() {
    return this.length * this.width;
  }
}
```

**static fields, methods**

Since state should be part of the components we cannot add instance fields to records. But, we can add static fields and methods:

```
record Rectangle(double length, double width) {

  static double aStaticField;

  static void aStaticMethod() {
    System.out.println("Hello Static");
  }
}
```

**what is the need of immutability and is there any advantage to using this?**

Previously posted answers are good enough to justify the need of immutability and it's pros

Answer (score 2):

**Immutable class** are those whose objects cannot be changed after creation.

Immutable classes is useful for

- Caching purpose
- Concurrent environment (ThreadSafe)
- Hard for inheritance
- Value cannot be changed in any environment

**Example**

String Class

**Code Example**

```
public final class Student {
    private final String name;
    private final String rollNumber;

    public Student(String name, String rollNumber) {
        this.name = name;
        this.rollNumber = rollNumber;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public String getRollNumber() {
        return this.rollNumber;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to make immutable object is using [Immutables.org](https://immutables.github.io/getstarted.html) library:

> Assuming that required dependencies were added, create an abstract
>   class with abstract accessor methods. You can do the same by
>   annotating with interfaces or even annotations (@interface):

```
package info.sample;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import org.immutables.value.Value;

@Value.Immutable
public abstract class FoobarValue {
  public abstract int foo();
  public abstract String bar();
  public abstract List<Integer> buz();
  public abstract Set<Long> crux();
}
```

> It is now possible to generate and then use the generated immutable
>   implementation:

```
package info.sample;

import java.util.List;

public class FoobarValueMain {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    FoobarValue value = ImmutableFoobarValue.builder()
        .foo(2)
        .bar("Bar")
        .addBuz(1, 3, 4)
        .build(); // FoobarValue{foo=2, bar=Bar, buz=[1, 3, 4], crux={}}

    int foo = value.foo(); // 2

    List<Integer> buz = value.buz(); // ImmutableList.of(1, 3, 4)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An immutable class is simply a class whose instances cannot be modified.

All ofthe information contained in each instance is fixed for the lifetime of the object, so no changes can ever be observed.

Immutable classes are easier to design, implement, and use than mutable classes.

To make a class immutable, follow these five rules:

1. Don’t provide methods that modify the object’s state
2. Ensure that the class can’t be extended.
3. Make all fields final.
4. Make all fields private.
5. Ensure exclusive access to any mutable components.

Immutable objects are inherently thread-safe; they require no synchronization.

Immutable objects can be shared freely.

Immutable objects make great building blocks for other objects

Answer (score 0):

@Jack, Having final fields and setters in class won't make class immutable. final keyword only make sure that a variable is never reassigned. You need to return deep copy of all fields in getter methods. This will make sure that, after getting a object from getter method, internal state of object is not disturbed.

Answer (score 0):

**Following are the requirements:**

- The class must be declared as
  `final` (So that child classes can’t be created)
- Data members in the class must be declared as `final` (So that we can’t
  change the value of it after object creation)
- A parameterized `constructor` should initialize all the fields
  performing a deep copy (So that data members can’t be modified with
  object reference)
- Deep Copy of objects should be performed in the `getter` methods (To
  return a copy rather than returning the actual object reference)
- No `setters` (To not have the option to change the value of the
  instance variable)

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
 
// An immutable class
public final class Student {
    private final String name;
    private final int regNo;
    private final Map<String, String> metadata;
 
    public Student(String name, int regNo,
                   Map<String, String> metadata)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.regNo = regNo;
        Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry :
             metadata.entrySet()) {
            tempMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        this.metadata = tempMap;
    }
 
    public String getName() { return name; }
 
    public int getRegNo() { return regNo; }
 
    public Map<String, String> getMetadata()
    {
        Map<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry :
             this.metadata.entrySet()) {
            tempMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
        return tempMap;
    }
}
 
// Driver class
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("1", "first");
        map.put("2", "second");
        Student s = new Student("ABC", 101, map);
        System.out.println(s.getName());
        System.out.println(s.getRegNo());
        System.out.println(s.getMetadata());
 
        // Uncommenting below line causes error
        // s.regNo = 102;
 
        map.put("3", "third");
        System.out.println(s.getMetadata()); // Remains unchanged due to deep copy in constructor
 
        s.getMetadata().put("4", "fourth");
        System.out.println(s.getMetadata()); // Remains unchanged due to deep copy in getter
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As a non-native English speaker, I dislike the common interpretation of "immutable class" being "constructed class objects are immutable"; rather, I myself lean to interpret that as "the class object itself is immutable".

That said, "immutable class" is a kind of immutable object. The difference is when answering what the benefit is. To my knowledge/interpretation, immutable class prevents its objects from runtime behavior modifications.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the answers here are good, and some mentioned the rules but I feel its good  to put down in words why& when we need to follow these rules. So am giving the below explanation

- Declare the member variables as ‘final’ – When we declare them as final , compiler forces us to initialize them. We can initialize directly, by default constructor, by arg constructor.( see sample code below)
  and after initialization we cannot modify them as they are final.
- And of course if we try to use Setters for those final variables, compiler throws error.

  ```
  public class ImmutableClassExplored {

      public final int a; 
      public final int b;

      /* OR  
      Generally we declare all properties as private, but declaring them as public 
      will not cause any issues in our scenario if we make them final     
      public final int a = 109;
      public final int b = 189;

       */
      ImmutableClassExplored(){
          this. a = 111;
          this.b = 222;
      }

      ImmutableClassExplored(int a, int b){
          this.a = a;
          this.b= b;
      }
  }
  ```

**Do we need to declare class as ‘final’?**

- Without final keyword in class declaration, class can be inherited. So subclass can override getter methods. Here we have to consider two scenarios:

**1. Having Only primitive members:** We do not have problem If class has only primitive members, then we do not need to declare class as final.

**2.Having Objects as member variables:** If we have objects as member variables then we have to make the members of those objects also final. Means we need to traverse deep down the tree and make all objects/primitives as final which may not be possible all the times. So the workaround is to make the class final which prevents inheritance. So there is no question of subclass overriding getter methods.

Answer (score -1):

@Value annotation of Lombok can be used to generate immutable classes. It's as simple as code below.

```
@Value
public class LombokImmutable {
    int id;
    String name;
}
```

As per documentation on Lombok's site:

> @Value is the immutable variant of @Data; all fields are made private and final by default, and setters are not generated. The class itself is also made final by default, because immutability is not something that can be forced onto a subclass. Like @Data, useful toString(), equals() and hashCode() methods are also generated, each field gets a getter method, and a constructor that covers every argument (except final fields that are initialized in the field declaration) is also generated.

A fully working example can be found [here.](http://www.devnips.com/2020/09/immutable-java-class-using-lombok.html)

Comment: Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for the green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Please take care when answering OP's question ***How can one make a Java class immutable, what is the need of immutability and is there any advantage to using this?***. – You're only giving a partial answer which just states that one can use Lombok, a third-party framework/library, which isn't necessarily what OP's question is about. Also Java 15 is out, why use Lombok when Java's `record` can be used?

Comment: I am giving one of the options of how to achieve this. Not everyone is using Java 15, majority of applications today are running on previous versions, so you saying why use Lombok doesn't make much sense. In my current project we recently migrated to Java 11 and are using Lombok to achieve immutable classes. Also, my answer is an addition to what answers were already present. What is immutable has already been answered, I guess you are expecting me to rewrite that just for completion.