# Best way to create variable with some static data

Tags: java

I would like to know, what is best way to create variable in Java.

I have country states, some int and some another int :

```
 USA -> {{"NY", 100, 100},{"CO", 200, 200},...}
 CAN -> {{"Quebec", 100, 100} ...}
```

There are some countries. I know I need create class, where I will put this data (state, integer, integer), but later I will want provide country and take only this countries data. Data will not change.

Should I put everything into one static variable or split into different vars?

Comment: How would you "put everything into one static variable"? And you need a collection of some sort.

Comment: Why not have a `Country` class with `String state` `int whatever` `int whatever2` fields? If there's ever a place for OOP, it's here. If you want this data to not change, you can make country immutable(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162665/immutable-class)

Comment: @Cruncher Ok I will create Country class, but how put data in it. What I mean, where should I initiate them (in contructor, ...)? Like create different variable for every Country, put into List or Map?

Comment: Make a Country class that accepts an array of States in the constructor. Then make a State class that accepts `String, int, int` in its consturctor.

Comment: Have enums really not been mentioned yet?

Comment: I know stupid question and maybe not clear, but thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
static class State {
    String name;
    int i1, i2;
    State(String name, int i1, int i2) {
        this.name = name;
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
    }
}

final static Map<String, Map<String, State>> countryStateMap;

static {
    countryStateMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, State> usa = new HashMap<>();
    usa.put("NY", new State("NY", 100, 100));
    usa.put("CO", new State("CO", 200, 200));

    Map<String, State> ca = new HashMap<>();
    ca.put("Quebec", new State("Quebec", 100, 100));

    // and so on

    countryStateMap.put("USA", usa);
    countryStateMap.put("CA", ca);
}
```

This uses a final static [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) an initializes it in a static block. The initialization is done a soon as the class is loaded.

Then you can use it like this in your code

```
Map<String, State> usaStates = countryStateMap.get("USA");
State ny = usaStates.get("NY");
```

Comment: Thanks @A4L This almost what I want. So just to conferm, you suggest to put coutryStateMap as static in some class and then call it in different class something like someClass.coutryStateMap.get("USA");. Will be more then 7 countries.

Answer (score 1):

As java is Object Oriented Programming, my suggestion would be model it as an object

```
class State{
  int code;
  String Name;
  int population;
  //other info
}

class Country{
int code;
String name
List<State> state;
// Other details
```

}

Now in a class create a Collection of Country

```
List<Country> countries;
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question as follows:

You want to store associations of country to collection-of-{sate, data1, data2}, and later access the collection that is associated with a specific country.

In this case you can use a `HashMap`, which provides just such association.  Assuming you have a `StateData` class that captures the {state, data1, data2} triple, you can write:

```
HashMap<String, Collection<StateData>> countries;
```

Populate the map with:

```
List<StateData> stateColl = new LinkedList<StateData>();
Map<String, List<StateData>> countries = new HashMap<String, List<StateData>>();
countries.put("USA", stateColl);
stateColl.add(stateData1);
stateColl.add(stateData2);
//...
```

where `stateData1`,... is of type `StateData`.  Note that you can use any collection that fits your needs instead of `LinkedList`.  You could also use a `TreeMap` instead of the `HashMap` if you need to store the countries in (alphabetical) order, but that comes with some performance hits.

Then access the state collections as:

```
List<StateData> stateColl = countries.get("USA");
for (StateData stateData : stateColl)
{
  // process the state info
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Attila you say similar to A4L, but I need info how to store it as he wrote.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a class to host the data you need to keep (String,int,int), something like this

```
class State{
private String name;
private int id,xyz;
//setter and getter methods
}
```

then you may need two lists/array, one for US, and another for CAN.

```
public class Foo{
private List<State> usGuys=new ArrayList<>();//you would use State[] instead
private List<State> canGuys=new ArrayList<>();
}
```

for keeping the instances you would either keep them withing `List` or `arrays`, it's up to you and the requirements.

but about your issue, you would keep all the data into one array/list, so in this case you need to add another attribute to `State` class to indicates the country 
`private String country`
but this may complex/make-it-hard the process in future because for example if you want to get all states in US, you need a for loop in order to check which states are belong to US, having multiple list may give you a better management
but what if the size of the countries is unknown!
simple enough, like you have list for storing states, you will have a list for keeping countries., something like this

```
class Country{
private List<State> states;
private String name;
}

class Foo{
private List<Countries> countries;
}
```

I hope I could give some hand.

Answer (score 1):

Enum will be ideal for storing this information. They are preferred way of storing constants since Java5.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done in one operation by using an initializer block. A minimal implementation to reprsent your data would be:

Create classes for your entities:

```
class Country {
    String shortName;
    List<State> states;
    Country(String s, State... stateArray) {
        shortName = s;
        states = Arrays.asList(stateArray);
    }
    // getters omitted
}

class State {
    String code;
    int num1, num2:
    State(String c, int n1, int n2) {
        cude = c;
        num1 = n1;
        num2 = n2;
    }
    // getters omitted
}
```

Then to create the variable:

```
List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>() {{
    add(new Country("USA", 
        new State("NU", 100, 100),
        new State("CO", 200, 200)
    );
    add(new Country("CAN",
        new State("Quebec", 100, 100)
    );
 }};
```