# Return immutable copy of mutable object from method

Tags: java, immutability

I have some closed component which is working over some XML object. I need to expose this object outside of this component, but I don't want to allow changes on it outside of my component. How can I complete this?

Comment: Make the class and all its fields `final`. This way you can create the object and initialize all fields just one time, you won't be able to modify the attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure your object has a [copy constructor](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12) that allows you to make a deeply-cloned copy of your class.

Then call this when you return the object, e.g.

```
SomeClass instance = // ....


public SomeClass getInstance() {
  return new SomeClass(instance);
}
```

This won't make the returned object immutable. But it doesn't need to be - you just don't want the external code making changes to *your* copy of the data.

Comment: The accepted solution is more like suggested here. I just created new object from class object and return it from method.

Comment: The semantics of returning a mutable object are a bit muddy, since it's not obvious whether the object may safely be regarded as a view of an object owned by the supplier, as a new object independent from the supplier, or neither.  If the method is returning a new instance, I prefer to explicitly say that in the name.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here is the access level's advocate ;-)

If you just wish to prevent the caller from *making* changes, it doesn't mean that it has to be immutable [in your package] - it just means that it shouldn't have a [public] way to mutate it :) I'm actually a growing fan of returning a *limiting public interface*.

For instance:

```
// Option A with a "limiting public interface"
public interface Awesome {
    public String getText();
}

class MyAwesome implements Awesome {
    public String getText() {
       // ..
    }
    // Option B is to make setText non-public
    public void setText() {
       // ..
    }
}
```

Then your code can return `Awesome` which doesn't [directly] provide a way  mutate the object.

Comment: +1 I tend to forget about this pattern, but I'm starting to like it too.

Comment: One difficulty with this approach is that it provides no indication to the caller as to whether the returned object may be persisted as a means of persisting its state.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create another class which is immutable, taking your object as a parameter (maybe in constructor). Then you should only expose the instance of your new class.

Here's some tips to make an object immutable: [Immutable class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162665/immutable-class)

Comment: "*Then you should only expose the instance of your new class*" > Can you explain this sentence?

Comment: Sure, the asker needs to expose an object:
`"I need to expose this object outside of this component"`.

I am telling that he/she should create another class, which is immutable, create an instance of that new class and expose that newly created object instead of the object he wanted to expose.