# How do I populate a Javascript array with a series of dates from a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

Here's the code I'm working on:

```js
    function populateDates() {
      var start = new Date(2017, 7, 13);
      var end = new Date(2017, 8, 3);
      var tempDate = start;
      var endPlus90 = end.setDate(end.getDate() + 90);
      var today = new Date();
      var array = [];
      for(var d = start; d < today || d < endPlus90; d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)){
        if (d.getDay() !== 0 && d.getDay() !== 6){
          array.push([d]);
        }
      }
      return array;
    }
    var future = new Date();
    future.setDate(future.getDate() + 90);
    console.log(populateDates(new Date(), future));
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is, given an arbitrary start and end date, generate a list of dates, excluding weekends, from the start date to either 90 days after the end date, or the current date, whichever is earlier. The current function generates an array that is all identical dates which are 90 days after the end date. I'm not very familiar with Javascript, so I'm not sure what's going wrong here. I suspect that the way I'm pushing the variable to the array is incorrect.

Comment: Have you tried to debbug?

Comment: Can you include example `start` and `end` arguments to the function at Question? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @giant enemy spycrab, Your question is unclear. When do you need to stop pushing dates? On end date or 90 days after start date (which is smaller)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem comes with your usage of `setDate` which returns

> The number of milliseconds between 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC and the given date (the Date object is also changed in place).
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

Wrap that `setDate` line in a `new Date()` and your code should run just fine.

---

As others pointed out the reason the array had multiples of the same date is because you were pushing references to the same single date object, and reassigning that object's date, which was updating it each of these references. By creating a new Date with `new Date()` you are creating a new object with its own reference.

Comment: It comes down to the philosophy of Immutable classes.  Read some more about what Immutable means in java, and you'll understand what happened in your code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162665/immutable-class

Comment: Don't forget to address why it will always print 90 days after the end date.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out. You need to initialize the `d` to a new Date every time. You can't just change the `day`. You also need to put `new Date()` around `end.setDate()`. `setDate()` returns milliseconds.

```
function populateDates(start, end) {
    var tempDate = start;
    var endPlus90 = new Date(end.setDate(end.getDate() + 90));
    var today = new Date();
    var array = [];
    for(var d = tempDate; d < endPlus90; d = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1))){ 
      if(d >= today) { // Stop counting dates if we reach the current date
        break;
      } 
      if (d.getDay() !== 0 && d.getDay() !== 6){
        array.push([d]);
      }
    }
    return array;
}

var future = new Date(); // As of 10/18/2017
future.setDate(future.getDate() + 90);
console.log(populateDates(new Date(2017, 9, 1), future)); // Prints 13 days as of 10/18/2017   
console.log(populateDates(new Date(2016, 9, 1), future)); // Prints 273 days
```